# How to fix a route in ad-hoc networks

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, networkmanager, ad-hoc-network

I have 4 raspberry PI connected through an ad-hoc network.
They have the following addresses:
**169.254.1.1

169.254.1.2

169.254.1.3

169.254.1.4**
I need to fix the route as follow:
**169.254.1.1** --> **169.254.1.2** --> **169.254.1.3** --> **169.254.1.4**
Currently, I'm using B.A.T.M.A.N. protocol for mesh ad-hoc networks.
I tried the **ip route add** command but it doesn't work.

---

**EDIT**
I tried to use ebtables to filter traffic from **MAC addresses** using

```
$ebtables -A INPUT -s [*mac address*] -j DROP
```

The rule is added correctly but it doesn't work, maybe I did something wrong with the syntax...

Comment: Since your 4 machines are within the same subnet 169.254.1/24, you don't have to do any routing between them at level 3 ( `ip route add` ). They see each other directly, unless you have done something special at the physical level. Please clarify in your OQ how is your network physically built.

Comment: I have 4 raspberry Pi connected in a wi-fi mesh network. They see each other directly but I need that a given device can accept frames only from a designed device. For example the device 4 can accept frames only from the device 3, device 3 instead can accept frames only from device 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a really old BATMAN, BATMAN routes on [layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.A.T.M.A.N.)

> In early 2007, the B.A.T.M.A.N. developers started experimenting with the idea of routing on layer 2 (Ethernet layer) instead of layer 3. To differentiate from the layer 3 routing daemon, the suffix "adv" (for: advanced) was chosen. Instead of manipulating routing tables based on information exchanged via UDP/IP, it provides a virtual network interface and transparently transports Ethernet packets on its own. The batman-adv kernel module has been part of the official Linux kernel since 2.6.38.

This means `ip route` entries will do exactly nothing, and if you want to control routing, you need to interact directly with BATMAN through the kernel interface (on `/proc`, if I remember correctly).

---

This may be seriously out of date, but back then I could use [batctl](https://downloads.open-mesh.org/batman/manpages/batctl.8.html) to get closer information about what a specific BATMAN node is doing, including neighbour lists, layer 2 ping, layer 2 traceroute, and internal debug tables.

It may or may not be possible to override neighbour and routing tables with that, I never tried.

My notes mention `/sys/kernel/debug/batman_adv/bat0/neighbors` and `/sys/class/net/*/batman_adv` (so it was on `/sys`, not on `/proc`), but I no longer run BATMAN, I forgot the details, and you may have to enable debugging in the kernel module somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some resources about it? because I can't find anything useful on the internet.